# I fear my dog wants to hurt my cats

Tags: cats, dogs

I recently adopted a Pitbull mix and she's a very friendly dog to people, but when she sees my cats she gets very focused and doesn't respond to her name, and if the cats get too close to the cage she will whine and bark. I fear she may see them as prey.

Comment: Have you read the past answers about how to introduce animals to each other?

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure this has been covered in other answers, but this is based on my own experience (though it's the inverse of yours.)

I have two *very highly* prey driven dogs. There is nothing that they would rather do, including eating the tastiest food, than to chase and kill small animals. It's sad, but there it is.

I was offered a "barn cat" (kitten, actually) that I could see was very much in need of a visit to a vet. The person offering him to me is a farmer, and She was having trouble getting these kittens a home, so I decided to take it in. My son, a cat lover, was very concerned about my decision, predicting my dogs would kill the kitten. Although I was also concerned, I reassured him that they would not.

Long story short(ish), the kitten lived in my (large) bathroom the first week, and I would only allow the dogs in while I was holding the kitten. They were very, very excited by the little animal and indeed tried to take the little guy right out of my arms, but were told "No."<sup>*</sup> Once that behavior was extinguished, I let my kitten walk on the floor nearby and, again, they would try to chase it or catch it, and I would intervene by shielding him with my hand, or if they were too rough, picking it up and ushering them out of the bathroom. It took about two weeks for the one dog and four for the other (a younger dog), but they now recognize him as a 'family member' and I have no worries when they're out together. When I go out, though, I kennel the dogs, but not the cat. The younger dog when in her kennel reacts with some excitement still when the cat walks very close to the kennel; I think she's just jealous she's not free, but I'm not taking any chances.

Giving the animals plenty of time to get used to each other under close supervision, usually apart at first, was key to the harmony we enjoy now. Dogs play differently than cats and the youngest can get a bit rough with the cat, but the dogs (well, the cat, too) want to be where I am, so they're pretty much always being observed, and it only takes a reminder to the dog to be gentle to get her to tone it down.

The only thing I have to add is that in my experience, barriers like fences and kennels make my dogs more excitable, not less, so your dog's excitement in the kennel isn't a surprise. It's been called [barrier frustration](https://www.chompsdogtraining.com/blog/dog-fence-fighting-causes-dangers-and-solutions). Having supervised, safe meetings without the dog being in the kennel might surprise you.

*<sub>I know the word "No" is controversial as opposed to a directional command ("Leave it", etc.) But I've had a lot of smart dogs (Border Collies) for decades, and they seem to interpret it as, "Stop whatever it is you're doing, and do something else." Sometimes, when it's absolutely too tempting to stop, my dogs now need to be redirected after the "No" not-a-command (they're not purebred Border Collies any more) with a "Settle" or some other command.I do thing they understand "No", though.</sub>